# docker-compose not found when running Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a Jenkins pipeline job on a remote agent node where it does a docker-compose to build my application. While running the pipeline it fails with the below exception. docker-compose is installed on the remote node and full permission is given to the executable. I have set the PATH in my Pipeline as well. Can someone help me?

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy to staging)
[Pipeline] echo
PATH is: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ /usr/bin/docker-compose up --build -d
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi@tmp/durable-060052a9/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi@tmp/durable-060052a9/script.sh: /usr/bin/docker-compose: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Snippet from my pipeline

```
pipeline {
    environment {
    registry = "sudheshpn/calculator"
    registryCredential = 'dockerhub'
    PATH = "$PATH:/usr/bin"
    dockerImage = ''
  }

        stage("Deploy to staging") {
              steps {
                    echo "PATH is: $PATH"
                    sh "/usr/bin/docker-compose up --build -d"
               }
        }
```

Remote agent config

```
root@ci-cd:/usr/bin# ls -ltr docker-compose
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 420 Apr 23 11:41 docker-compose
root@ci-cd:/usr/bin# pwd
/usr/bin
root@ci-cd:/usr/bin# docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.21.0, build unknown
```

Manually execution from the remote node is working

```
root@ci-cd:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi# /usr/bin/docker-compose up --build -d
Building calculator
Step 1/7 : FROM williamyeh/java8
 ---> 00bc163fa009
Step 2/7 : ADD build/libs/calculator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31096985299e
```

Comment: Currently i have set the agent as any and the directory is getting created on on CI-CD server on /var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi. I dont think the build process is running on my jenkins master node.

Comment: Check if your Jenkins user have permission to run the docker command without sudo. As per your problem statement you are running the steps manually with root user.  Try the same steps with Jenkins user in VM and see you are facing same pipeline issue.

Comment: This is what i get when i run as jenkins user.    docker-compose up -d
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?
If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

Comment: Expected behaviour. Try this changes mentioned in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638772/make-jenkins-run-docker-without-sudo

Comment: please post your error in clean format, somewhere in gist file and then link to gist. difficult to read

Comment: I have added jenkins user to the docker group and i am able to do docker ps,build as jenkins user, however the problem still exist when i run as a pipeline job. 

 root@ci-cd:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi# su jenkins
jenkins@ci-cd:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi$ cd /var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi
jenkins@ci-cd:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi$ /usr/bin/docker-compose up --build -d
Building calculator
Step 1/7 : FROM williamyeh/java8
 ---> 00bc163fa009
Step 2/7 : ADD build/libs/calculator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
 ---> Using cache

Comment: able to build the image with Jenkins user in local VM ?

Comment: As jenkins user i am able to build my image. Please find the final output
`
Successfully built d746aa62d47f
Successfully tagged calc_multi_calculator:latest
calc_multi_redis_1 is up-to-date
Recreating calc_multi_calculator_1 ... done
jenkins@ci-cd:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi$
`

Comment: So, Eliminated user permission thought. Now Jenkins cannot understand where is docker-compose installed(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481322/docker-compose-command-not-found-on-jenkins?rq=1). can you please check as build is getting exited in middle so there will be junk container? So check if they are on salve node or master node.

Comment: I dont see any exited containers which was started by the jenkins both on master and slave. For testing purpose i created a job to be executed as a shell and i am able to do ls to /usr/bin/docker-compose ,do docker ps however the when trying to execute docker-compose it says file not found

Comment: sh  "cd /var/jenkins_home/workspace/calc_multi && /usr/bin/docker-compose up --build -d"  can you please add this and rerun the job?                                                            I am trying to **cd in to your workspace where dockerfile is present and then docker-compose command**  I can see in my own pipeline I have written like that.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is that you need to define the remote agent node label in pipeline else you should have `docker-compose` installed on the Jenkins master itself -

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'ci-cd' }
    stages {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

docker compose is installed on the remote node but the agent you defined is a docker. is docker-compose installed on the docker `sudheshpn/calculator`?

I would personally won't recommend to use docker-compose in pipeline. It is a tool for development not for CI. For CI I would use docker alone or jenkins kubernetes plugin to deploy a pod of containers at once